# comparing consecutive elements in an array returns nothing (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm doing some exercises and having a hard time figuring out why my code won't work, would be glad if someone can point me in the right direction. So my input is a string of numbers, which I .split to get an array of strings (so I can loop trough it). Then I want to compare if the strings are equal to the next one or not, and use it to do something (here I'm just printing out the status). Can't figure out what I did wrong, code below.

```js
var line = "40 40 40 40 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 57 57 92 92 92 92 92 86 86";

line = line.split(" ");

for (x = 0; x < line.lenght; x++) {
  if (line[x] == line[x + 1]) {
    console.log("numbers are the same");
  } else if (line[x] !== line[x + 1]) {
    console.log("numbers aren't the same");
  }
}
```

Comment: * line.length - not lenght.

Comment: also the `else if()` is useless, just go for an `else()`

Comment: `for (x = 0; x < line.length - 1; x++)`( typo and dereference beyond upper array bound). Consider using the type-safe equality test (`===` instead of `==`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled `length` so that's why it's not logging plus when you're on the last array item you'll go out of bounds with `line[x + 1]`.

Comment: well if it goes out of bound, it'll just return number not the same, because there's nothing there to compare it to, right?

Comment: That's technically right in this example but in general do not rely on things like that, it's not comparing numbers/strings anymore because you're looking for an array element that doesn't exist (that will return "undefined").

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo: length instead of lenght and your code is good to go.

Comment: accepted JohnIdol's anwser, since he was a bit quicker